# Accessing field from another class

Tags: c#

How is the `ModelDuck` constructor able to access the fields in the `Duck` class - `flyBehaviour` and `quackBehaviour`. Thanks

```
namespace HeadFirst
{
    public class ModelDuck : Duck
    {

        public ModelDuck()
        {
            flyBehaviour = new FlyNoWay();
            quackBehaviour = new Quack();
        }
        public override void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a model duck");
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Duck
{
    public FlyBehaviour flyBehaviour;
    public QuackBehaviour quackBehaviour;

    public Duck()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really basic question I'm afraid, I would recommend that you go read a book on C# or run through some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties belong the the base class.

You should always be able to acces the properties and methods of your base class

Comment: These are fields not properties.

Comment: Same thing. You can still acces them